# Null Pointer exception Java Web Application

Tags: jsp, javabeans

So, I have a jsp file (ShowProducCatalog.jsp) that is trying to access retrieve data from a mysql database through a javabean (ProductDataBean.java). I am using netbeans IDE. I have made sure the server is running by creating tables from the netbeans ids and viewing the same table in the mysql workbench. But each time i start my application i get this error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page     /ShowProductCatalog.jsp at line 9
6: 
7: <html>
8:     <body>
9:         <%  List productList = data.getProductList();
10:             Iterator prodListIterator = productList.iterator();
11:           %>
12:
```

And the root cause is from my bean 
root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    cart.ProductDataBean.getProductList(ProductDataBean.java:36)
    org.apache.jsp.ShowProductCatalog_jsp._jspService(ShowProductCatalog_jsp.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Here is my ProductDataBean section where the error comes form:

```
public class ProductDataBean implements Serializable
{
    private static Connection connection;

    public ProductDataBean()
    {
        try
        {
                String userName = "root";
                String password = "root";
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:/eshopdb";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
                System.out.println("Database connection established");
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }

    public ArrayList getProductList() throws SQLException
    {
        ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();//ERROR HERE
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM product");

        while (results.next())
        {...
```

Seems like the connection variable is never initialized or something! but my username, password and url are correct. Help please!

Comment: Normally when posting it's nice to be explicit regarding the line the error occurs on.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use generics, or the JSTL's `<c:forEach>`?  Try not to put Java code in the JSP.  Instead, have your application make `productList` a request attribute.  Have you unit tests?

Comment: I have specified the line of code where the error comes from. it is in the bean. I am very new to web development in java. This is one of my first labs

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

```
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/eshopdb";
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

This assumes that you're using the default port 3306.

You should not go down this route. Scriptlet code in JSPs is 1998 vintage stuff - long discredited.

Your `ProductDataBean` should not be acquiring a database connection - at least not this way.  Connection pooling is the way to go.

You don't appear to clean up any resources.  This app will crash in short order, because you'll run out of connections and cursors in the database.

Comment: i have added the default port 3306 it does not work. I don't see any difference with what is in the link. What is wrong with mine?

Comment: I am very new to web development in Java. Connection pooling will be another new concept to me. And honestly i don't have time. I don't mean to be rude by disregarding your solution, but if i only had this means to do it, how will that be possible?